# Minimum fire resist to counteract vampirism weakness

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

How much fire resist from glyphs is needed to negate the weakness to fire debuff from vampirism?

Comment: I think your fire resist spell cap is lowered as a vampire. So I don't think it is ever possible to negate all of the bonus damage.

Comment: the way I see it, if you're going to do fire-resist on one of your jewelery items as a vampire (and you should), you should just do as much as possible, period. Nonetheless, this is a good question :3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the Vampire builds for a Nightblade insist on only getting a **single Ring with a crafted 1000 Fire Resistance bonus**. This will also reach the fire resistance soft cap.

For example, take [Kutsuu's build](http://tamrielfoundry.com/topic/kutsuus-vampire-juggernaut/). It's a mass-DPS build with Vampire tree.
This guy is known to do the maths about his character and he explains quite simple and precise.

So in short term, with Vampire tree it's only possible to negate the Vampire fire damage debuff, but you won't get more out of it because of the soft cap. That's why some Vampire builds rely on Light Armor, where you can **get additional Spell Damage Reduction**. (Fire Damage and Spell Damage are reduced seperately.)